# What type should I use for year-only columns?

Tags: sql, oracle, date, create-table

I am trying to create a table in Oracle a would like to make a data type that is a year:

```
create table testingTable
(
testID varchar2(3) primary key,
dateDeveloped year(4)
);
```

The error message I am getting with this is

```
Error at Command Line : 16 Column : 19
Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis
00907. 00000 -  "missing right parenthesis"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

Thank you for your time.

Comment: What range should the new data type have?  1900 and later?  8000 BC to 300,000 AD?   Should it reject year 0?

Answer (score 2):

*In order to have the community opinion on "how to store year only in a table", I've posted two diametrically opposite answers. I've made them community wiki, so feel free to vote up or down according to your opinion.*

---

If you only want to store 4-digit years, why should you bother with the `DATE` type? Use a `NUMBER(4)`  instead:

```
create table testingTable
(
  testID varchar2(3) primary key,
  yearDeveloped number(4)
);
```

That way, you will have direct access to the year when using your field.

Comment: That is a good point.  I just have a preference for defining data types as specifically as possible, so if it were possible to label something as a year, I wanted to do that.  I am going with your solution.  Thanks again.

Comment: dateDeveloped - i would rename that to 'yearDeveloped' - anyone seeing that later will assume it's a date.

Comment: @Sylvain, I would use either of your suggestions, both will work just as well as the other. The NUMBER version is probably less confusing for future developers; however, the DATE version may be more convenient for date arithmetic. On balance I prefer the NUMBER version though.

Answer (score 1):

*In order to have the community opinion on "how to store year only in a table", I've posted two diametrically opposite answers. I've made them community wiki, so feel free to vote up or down according to your opinion.*

---

If you want to store "point in time" you should use the `DATE` type:

```
create table testingTable
(
  testID varchar2(3) primary key,
  dateDeveloped date
);
```

If you are only interested in the year component, it is up to you to extract that when using that field:

```
extract(year from dateDeveloped)
```

At insert time, you will convert the 4-digit year to a proper date:

```
to_date('1984', 'YYYY') -- evaluating to the rather surprising 11/01/1984
```

Comment: Thanks, @Sylvain.  The issue is how we enter information.  I don't think we will have anything more specific than the year.  Is there a convention that people follow like 1976-00-00 for dates that only have a year?

Comment: @Grace: A date doesn't have only a year. If the only thing you have is a year, you have a year. For example, *1986* isn't a valid date of birth. It's a year.

Comment: I'd agree with @thatjeffsmith that it should be `yearDeveloped`; the column already has the `date` datatype, but you want to convey the fact that only the year portion is significant. P.S. on insert I would always truncate to 1-Jan, and put a constraint on the table to disallow other dates.

Comment: @Jeffrey Good idea about the constraint. Could you edit the answer accordingly? It is a community wiki without rep gain for anyone, but I believe this might be a very good improvement.

Comment: @Mike Sherrill 'Cat Recall' I tried year as a data type (see original post), but it didn't work with Oracle.  The best solution I have so far is number(4)...  As wallyk pointed out, this may not matter depending on the range of dates one wants to include.  Thanks everyone for the input!

Comment: First, year() isn't a data type. It's a function. Second, I didn't suggest using year as a data type. I just said that a year wasn't a date. To store a year in any SQL database, I'd use either some kind of integer or numeric data type along with a check() constraint.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you were using wrong syntax. It should be something like this.

```
INTERVAL YEAR (precision) TO MONTH
```

A period of time, represented as years and months. The precision value specifies the number of digits in the YEAR field of the date. The precision can be from 0 to 9, and defaults to 2 for years. [**Check here**](http://www.oracle-dba-online.com/sql/oracle_datatypes_and_create_table.htm) for more info

```
create table testingTable
(
testID varchar2(3) primary key,
dateDeveloped INTERVAL YEAR(4) TO MONTH
);
```

Comment: Does he want to store, years, as in amount of time passed, or an actual year? Might want to go with DATE instead of interval, but I don't think we know enough to know for sure.

Comment: Thank you both. I wanted to store the information as a year something happened rather than the number of years.  I did try to use DATE, but couldn't get that to work.

Comment: Does interval not store the year? (@NoDisplayName, there is an extra parenthesis after month that I tried to edit out so the code would run as is, but I can't edit without changing 6 characters...)  Also, can anyone shed light on why we need "to month" when we are trying to store years? Thanks again!

Comment: An interval is -well- a period of (rather than a point in) time. And as a year is rather a period of than a point in time, the Oracle reading of an intervall is closer to be 1 year (than 2014) for, e.g., 2014-01-01 00:00:00 to 2014-12-31 23:59:59. The options for storing the year (portion of a date) have been offered above - each with its own peculiarities (in short: clarity vs. ease of use / duration of vs. point in time)